# ayuda con el certificado ssl

Tags: ssl, glassfish

si bien no entiendo bien como funciona el tema de los certificados ssl paso a comentar que active el http/2 de glassfish. El problema es que cada vez que me conecto me da error de "conexion no es segura" o invalid secrity certificate.

Para entender mas o menos lo que hice fue ir a glassfish a la consola de administración activar el puerto 8181 y darle el certificado que viene por defecto s1as!

Si alguien me podria ayudar.

Comment: pon https al principio en lugar de http

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, si eso hago sin el https no se conecta, pero el problema es que me dice error de certificado y me molesta quiero pase derecho si supuestamente el certificado es de mi server, se supone que es mi comunicacion encriptada.

Answer (score 0):

El puerto debe está abierto en el firewall; y se debe colocar en la url, de no querer usar el 8181, cambia a 443, ya no sería necesario colocarlo en le URL
saludos

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)